# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str， for osm_road in self.get_osm_objs()['road']:

Tags: python

When I run this code

```
def diff(self):
    for osm_road in self.get_osm_objs()['road']:
        osm_points = self.get_keypoints(osm_road.id)
        for mdm_road in self.get_mdm_road():
            mdm_points = mdm_road.shape
            if match().macth_by_mutiPoints(mdm_points,osm_points):
                if osm_road.tags['LINE_TYPE'] == "RoadCenter" and mdm_road.TravelDirection_type != 2:
                    print(osm_road.tags)
                    self.output_info('mxf中的poi{}和mdm中的poi{}的type不一致'.format(osm_road.id,mdm_road.id.count))
                if osm_road.tags['LINE_TYPE'] == "RoadCenter" and mdm_road.length != 2:
                    self.output_info('mxf中的poi{}和mdm中的poi{}的type不一致'.format(osm_road.id,mdm_road.id.count))
                if osm_road.tags['LINE_TYPE'] == "RoadCenter" and mdm_road.road_type != 2:
                    self.output_info('mxf中的poi{}和mdm中的poi{}的type不一致'.format(osm_road.id,mdm_road.id.count))
                    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ROAD_diff("msd_1.0.xml", "mdm_1598425741707.db", "result.txt").diff()
```

I get this error

```
    for osm_road in self.get_osm_objs()['road']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

how do I fix it?

Comment: Its hard to say because I don't know what `get_osm_objs` is, but it appears to be returning a `list`, not a `dict`. Is there any reason you'd expect it to be a `dict` or that `['raod']` is the right thing to do? Can you give us more details on what this API is?

Comment: This is where a good visual debugger would be very helpful.  You could stop on the line that is giving you trouble, and see in the debugger what `self.get_osm_objs()` really is.  You could also print out what that value is, or print its type with `print(type(self.get_osm_objs()))`.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I'm wondering if you don't want to change the problem line to `for osm in self.get_osm_objs():` and then add a line below that `osm_road = osm['road']`.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code, like the code for `ROAD_diff`?  Is `ROAD_diff` a class of which the `diff` function you show is a method?